# J2ME Record deletion problem in RecordStore

Tags: java-me, rms, recordstore

I am using a recordstore to store some data,and each data is being shown in form of list elements.In my application,i am having a feature in which i can delete a particular list element.When i perform this action,item is getting deleted from the list but it is not working with the record.
I dont know why?
Can any one help me?
My code snippet is:

```
 int x=list.getSelectedIndex();
             list.delete(x);
             try
             {
                rs_store.deleteRecord(x);
             }
             catch(Exception error)
             {
                 System.out.print("error");
             }
```

`display.setCurrent(list);`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If the indices of the items in your `List` are supposed to correspond with the indices of items in your `RecordStore`, then your problem may be down to the fact that `RecordStore` entries are 1-based, not 0-based.

So element 0 in your list will correspond to record 1 etc.

Comment: but the problem is no record is being deleted from the recordstore.

Comment: Is any exception being thrown?